# Ambiguous deduction with shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I've encountered a weird issue regarding the initializer list return.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>, bool> function() { return {{}, false}; } //not fine

std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>, bool> function2() { return {nullptr, false}; } //fine

auto main() -> int{}
```

Code won't compile with g++ (versions 11+, it works fine in g++-10 and clang-14).

Build fails with:

```
./main.cpp:4:70: error: conversion from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>, bool>’ is ambiguous
    4 | std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>, bool> function() { return {{}, false}; }
      |                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/bits/unique_ptr.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12/memory:76,
                 from ./main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12/tuple:1155:9: note: candidate: ‘std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple(std::allocator_arg_t, const _Alloc&) [with _Alloc = bool; typename std::enable_if<std::_TupleConstraints<std::is_object<_Alloc>::value, _T1, _T2>::__is_implicitly_default_constructible(), bool>::type <anonymous> = true; _T1 = std::sha
red_ptr<int>; _T2 = bool]’
 1155 |         tuple(allocator_arg_t __tag, const _Alloc& __a)
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12/tuple:1063:9: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with bool _Dummy = true; typename std::enable_if<std::_TupleConstraints<_Dummy, _T1, _T2>::__is_implicitly_constructible<const _T1&, const _T2&>(), bool>::type <anonymous> = true; _T1 = std::shared_p
tr<int>; _T2 = bool]’
 1063 |         tuple(const _T1& __a1, const _T2& __a2)
      |         ^~~~~
```

Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: It actually says right there in the log. There are two constructors that it could be referring to: the one that takes `std::allocator_arg_t` as the first constructor argument, or the one that takes `const T1&, const T2&`.  I'm not sure what the standard expects this to be, but I would expect the failure to be correct. Also this isn't deduction at all, this is overload resolution

Comment: Sure, but why does clang compile and gcc does not?

Comment: Well, for starters, they are using different standard libraries authored by different developers. Could just be that the standard is under-specified. As far as I can see, the standard only states that there are expected preconditions that the allocator argument for `std::allocator_arg_t` is a valid allocator, but it's not _required_ to be a SFINAE requirement. It's completely legal/valid for LLVM's libc++ to implement it this way, just as it would be legal for gcc's libstdc++ to leave it ambiguous.

Comment: Clang still compiles it even with libstdc++, so it seems like a either GCC or Clang have a bug here. MSVC agrees with Clang FWIW...